# How to get variable from spring application.yaml in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have app.name in my application.yaml

How do i access this please, I was hoping for a simple one liner.

@Values doesn't seem to work, it only works in my restcontroller. I've created a configurationproperties and a EnableConfigurationProperties, but no one will tell me how to actually get a value from the properties.

```
class databaseHandler() {

@Value("\${app.url}")
private val url: String? = null

fun dave(){
 print(url)
} ==Null
```

==

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
class appConfig(){
   lateinit var url: String
}


@EnableConfigurationProperties(appConfig::class)
class dave(){
fun dave(){
 print(appConfig().url)
} ==Lateinit url hasn't been initalized
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue, You need to initialise your sub-class as well and also declare it as a spring component e.g.

```
@Service
class DatabaseHelper {
    @Value("\${app.url}")
    val url= ""
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class GitHubController{

    @Autowired
    lateinit var databaseHelper : DatabaseHelper 

    @GetMapping("")
    fun hello() = "hello $databaseHelper.url"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `application.yml` has the following properties:

```
app-url: www.demo-url.com
```

Add`@EnableConfigurationProperties` to your binding class i.e.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
class appConfig() {
   lateinit var url: String
}
```

> @EnableConfigurationProperties this annotation is used to enable @ConfigurationProperties annotated beans in the Spring application

Please refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml

Comment: Gives me kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property url has not been initialized